# Are apps that bypass the System Print Dialog allowed in the Mac App Store?

Tags: cocoa, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

Is it allowed (also considering sandboxing) to have your app bypass the system print dialog and directly talk to the printer when you want to publish it through the Mac App Store?

I know that you should use the system print dialog wherever possible. This is a for a special app with special color management requirements, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only using public APIs and there's no specific guideline forbidding it in the App Store submission guidelines, then I imagine it'll be OK - especially since you have a specific reason to.

If it's not mentioned in the guidelines, you're going to have to suck it and see by submitting it to Apple.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid so. I guess I'll need to request the USB entitlement and then hopefully the sandbox won't ruin my day :)